# iOS How to receive and store system NSNotification in a SwiftUI application?

Tags: ios, swiftui, core-data, uikit, nsnotificationcenter

I want to write an app where I create a database of all the changes made in one setting from UIKit.
The flow in SwiftUI:

1. UIKit posts a notification (static let Name_StatusDidChangeNotification: NSNotifiaction.Name)
2. My Swift App saves current DateTime in Core Data - both while in foreground and background mode

How should I design my app to be able to do this?

This is my first time creating an iOS app. From my research I think that:

1. I need to create  `DataController : ObservableObject`
   -> to controll the data  being loaded and saved to the device.
2. I need to create  `AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {}`
3. In my **@main** struct I need to add

```
@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(Appdelegate.self) var appDelegate
```

I got stuck in the middle because I do not know how to configure my notification center. Where it should be added?

```
NotificationCenter.default
                    .addObserver(self,
                      selector:#selector(mySelector),
                 name: NSNotification.Name("Name_StatusDidChangeNotification"),
                      object:nil)


@objc func mySelector(_ notification: Notification) {
//saving DateTime into Storage
}
```